# Create a new element for every item in an array, appending (issue)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, appendchild

My issue is that every time I press the button it keeps adding. I want it to replace it self.

It's likely that there are better ways to approach this.
I want to be able to present all the data in an array, with one new element per item in the array.

I only use vanilla JS

```js
const reBtn = document.getElementById("reBtn");

reBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myfunc();
});

let sortedList = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
let addParagraph = document.createElement("ul");

function myfunc() {
  sortedList.forEach(function (i) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = i;
    addParagraph.appendChild(li);
    resultLeft.appendChild(addParagraph);
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="reBtn">Result</button>

<div id="resultLeft"></div>
```

Comment: Give your `li` an id and check for it before appending it in the loop

Comment: But that wouldn't work if the array changed, would it? The array here is just a mock one. The real one changes depending on input.

Comment: Use the index of the item inside the array? Or it's value? Something that is comparable?

Comment: You lost me there, sorry. How would you go about that? (I'm a newbie)

Comment: What is the defining element of the array that you don't want to duplicate? The value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const reBtn = document.getElementById("reBtn");

reBtn.addEventListener("click", myfunc)

const sortedList = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
const ulElement = document.createElement("ul");

function myfunc() {
  ulElement.textContent = ""
  sortedList.forEach(function (i) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = i + " [" + new Date().getSeconds() + "]";
    ulElement.appendChild(li);
  });
  resultLeft.appendChild(ulElement);
}
```

```html
<button id="reBtn">Result</button>

<div id="resultLeft"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for thee answer so far it fits my code good! and most importantly I think I understand it, which is important to me, so I can develop.
Its one thing I don't get (+ " [" + new Date().getSeconds() + "]") what does it do? / why would you use it? 
Thanks again!!

Comment: @EmKl `+ " [" + new Date().getSeconds() + "]"` you can remove this. I've added this only to show that data is being replaced. It's just adding seconds and it's not necessary.

Comment: Yes I did understand that I could remove it (after awhile) :D 
I was just curious if it was something I should implement / learn more about. But now it makes sens. Thanks again It did what it suppose to do!

Answer (score 1):

You keep adding to your UL without deleting any of the li's.  Hence unless you remove it and create a new UL you will keep adding to it.

```js
const reBtn = document.getElementById("reBtn");
const resultLeft = document.getElementById('resultLeft')

reBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myfunc();
});

let sortedList = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]];
let cnt = 0;

function myfunc() {
 
 while( resultLeft.firstChild ){  
  resultLeft.removeChild( resultLeft.firstChild );
}

let addParagraph = document.createElement("ul");

 
  sortedList[cnt].forEach(function (i) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = i;
    addParagraph.appendChild(li);
    resultLeft.appendChild(addParagraph);
  });
  cnt++
  
  cnt = cnt%2
}
```

```html
<button id="reBtn">Result</button>

<div id="resultLeft"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I went with #ulou solution. 
just want to ask some questions about you code,
Why do you have a nested array? I played with everybodys code to see what would fit me and yours broke when I made the array just simple [1,2,3,4]. Whys that? 
And the cnt, I understand its a counter but can't see you are using it?

Comment: I went with a nested array as a way to show you what happens when you hit the submit button more than once. cnt is used in the forEach statement and adjusted at the end of the function to always be 0 or 1. The main point in all these solutions is you need to remove or clear the Li’s from the ul each time you hit the submit button

Comment: Yes. when I was looking around for solutions I understod that, but I tried to implement a function that to empty parent or child I never got it to work. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.innerHTML = ""` to clear the current children from your UL - before rebuilding the LIs from the updated array:

```js
const list = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

const newEL = (sel, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), prop); 
const EL_list = document.querySelector("#resultLeft");
const EL_btn  = document.getElementById("reBtn");

const populateList = () => {
  EL_list.innerHTML = ""; // Clear all
  list.forEach(val => {
    const LI = newEL("li", {textContent: val});
    EL_list.append(LI);
  });
}
EL_btn.addEventListener("click", populateList);
```

```html
<button id="reBtn">Result</button>

<ul id="resultLeft"></ul>
```

Example using DocumentFragment and Array.prototype.reduce

```js
const list = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

const newEL = (sel, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), prop); 
const EL_list = document.querySelector("#resultLeft");
const EL_btn  = document.getElementById("reBtn");

const populateList = () => {
  EL_list.innerHTML = "";  // Clear all
  const LIS = list.reduce((DF, val) => {  
    DF.append(newEL("li", {textContent: val}));
    return DF
  }, new DocumentFragment());
  EL_list.append(LIS);
}
EL_btn.addEventListener("click", populateList);
```

```html
<button id="reBtn">Result</button>

<ul id="resultLeft"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I went with #ulou solution, but yours works. Its a lot in you code I don't really know what and how it work, But I have noted in my list of thing to learn (DocumentFragment) and continue with arrow function and make the code shorter